# How to use enum in objective c

Tags: objective-c, enums

I am abit stuck on how I use enum's in my project, I have set up the the enum object but I would like to know how to use it.

This is what I have done so far

**//.h**

```
   typedef enum {
      ktUnknown=0, ktSingleSided=1, ktDoubleSided=2, ktTripleSingleSided=3
    } TICKType;
    //..
    TICKType Type;
    //..
    @property (assign) TICKType Type;
```

Now I would like to know how to check if an integer equals one of those enum types in an if statement.

this is kinda what im doing obviously not working

```
if (myobj.objsval == Type.ktSingleSided) {

}
```

but unfortunately this is not working. any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Drop the `Type.` and just use `myobj.objsval == ktSingleSided`, including the double equal sign.

Comment: oh, so do I still keep Type declared in the .h file (oppps ill fix formating)

Comment: Unlike C# and other languages, you don't need to prefix enums with their type name.  In fact you could have a completely anonymous enum with no type name at all.

Comment: @Mahesh no error message at the moment because I didnt even know how to access ktSingleSided untill bobnoble answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 typedef enum {
      ktUnknown=0, ktSingleSided=1, ktDoubleSided=2, ktTripleSingleSided=3
    } TICKType;
```

enum can be compared to integer value only if `myobj.objsval` is a integer property

```
if (myobj.objsval == ktSingleSided) the this condition will be satisfied
```

Answer (score 1):

in OC use enum like this

```
if (myobj.objsval == ktSingleSided){
}
```

you don't need to type declared here.